# ReadToEndAsync is blocking, how to get it to run asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stream

I call this getJson() function from an async action in my controller.
I have a list of large files that each take a few seconds for ReadToEndAsync() to process.
The ReadToEndAsync() is blocking even though I'm awaiting it.

How can I call ReadToEndAsync() asynchronously?

```
public static async Task<T> getJson<T>(String url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server + url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

    String jsonString;
    //get the json string from the response
    using (var xx = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xx, Encoding.UTF8);
        jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
    }
}
```

### Controller:

```
_model.list.Add(await DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url));
_model.list.Add(await DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url));
_model.list.Add(await DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url));
```

Comment: ReadToEndAsync() is  blocking because you are awaiting!

Comment: If i don't await it, it still blocks. How can I get it to run asynchronously?

Comment: @RjGeraci: How do you know that it's blocking?

Comment: In the debugger, no other code is executed until it returns.

Comment: @RjGeraci pause the debugger while ReadToEndAsync (allegedly) runs. What's on the stack? Is it really ReadToEndAsync?

Comment: @usr yes. The stream is large.

Comment: Post the full stack showing external code as well.

Comment: @usr Source Not Available Code not running. The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained.

Comment: Use the threads window to find the right thread. Or post any other proof that ReadToEndAsync is actually blocking this thread. I do not understand how you made sure that ReadToEndAsync is indeed the blocking function.

Comment: Once I step over the call to ReadToEndAsync I click pause. There are several threads, but all of them give the message I posted above.

Comment: @usr if i change the call to ReadToEnd() the top of the stack is external code: "> System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags, out System.Net.Sockets.SocketError errorCode) Unknown"

Comment: @RjGeraci the VS debugger is async aware. If you step over it will pause when the await call is finished. So probably ReadToEndAsync is async but the debugger hides that from you. Does that make sense? Do you still think that the call is blocking?

Comment: Are you waiting to get called back on your synchronization context because you didn't do `.ConfigureAwait(false)`? :-o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, while the method `ReadToEndAsync()` does *not* block per se – in the usual sense of the word "block": that is, the thread that calls that method continues to run – it certainly will prevent the code after the `await` from executing until the method has completed. Which is exactly what you want: you don't want that code to execute until the read has completed, otherwise it wouldn't have the result to operate on.

You should probably (re?)read the documentation on `async` and `await`, but briefly: the keyword `async` is applied to a method to signal to the compiler that it will use `await`. The `await` is used to indicate to the compiler a point in the method where the compiler should save the current execution state of the method ***and return***.

If and when the operation to which the `await` keyword has been applied completes, the framework will automatically continue execution of the method where it left off. Where the method is called in a thread that is tied to a synchronization context (e.g. a GUI thread in a Winforms or WPF program), by default this "continuation" is executed in that original thread (but this can be disabled when appropriate).

Please note above that the `async` method *returns* from `await` statements. Thus, the method itself does not block the thread, even as the operation represented by the method does "block" in some sense of the word.

So, with that all said, it seems to me that you may be trying to get your three operations to all complete asynchronously and concurrently. If you want to do that, you need to start all of the asynchronous operations at once, rather than waiting for each to complete before proceeding to the next as you do now (i.e. via the `await` statement applied to the call to the `getJason<T>()` method).

That would look something like this:

```
Task<ReviewModel> task1 = DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url1),
    task2 = DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url2),
    task3 = DataRetriever.getJson<ReviewModel>(url3);

_model.list.Add(await task1);
_model.list.Add(await task2);
_model.list.Add(await task3);
```

(Note: in your original code example, you only used a single `url` value. Since I assume you don't really want to just execute the same query three different times, I went ahead and changed the code example so that each task uses a different value).

In the above, even if the second and/or third task completes before the first, the results will be added to the result list in order. **But** the tasks themselves are started all at the same time so that they can run concurrently.

I hope that the above not only clarifies for you whether or not the call to the method `ReadToEndAsync()` is blocking (it does not, though because of the way the debugger presents the execution of your code, it might *seem* that it does), but also provides you with the solution to the larger problem that led you to debug the method and *think* that it's blocking. I.e. that your JSON queries didn't execute concurrently.

If between the comments on your question, and the above answer, you still have a problem, please edit your question so that it's more clear about what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Good answer, but your description `await` resuming in the same thread is incorrect. Only the UI-based contexts are tied to a single thread; ASP.NET works very differently. The ASP.NET context is a "request context", so it's perfectly valid (and common) for an `await` on ASP.NET to resume on another thread, as long as that "request context" has been moved to the resuming thread.

Comment: @StephenCleary: thanks for the clarification. I agree it was a mistake to so broadly lump the ASP.NET behavior in with the thread-owned-context model of the GUI APIs; I'll reword that passage.

Comment: Thanks that does clear things up a bit. I actually am executing the same query three times, the server returns a random object.

Comment: Since you are awaiting each task seperate: Perhaps `Task.WhenAll` is better? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JP: using `WhenAll()` would be an unnecessary complication, especially since all the values need to be unpacked and added to the list anyway. Also, your edit turned valid code into invalid code, and frankly even if it had been valid, did not improve the code in any way. The change was a completely subjective one. Please find the Meta discussions on when and how to edit posts and be careful to follow that guidance closely.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thank you for the explanation. I missed the comma's. You are right.